# Add column containing daily values derived from cumulative totals in R based on groupings

Tags: r, calculated-columns

fairly new to R and tearing my hair out with this at the minute so I really appreciate any help; I'm using the COVID-19 package from the COVID-19 DataHub; within the dataset, the data on confirmed cases, deaths and recoveries for each day is cumulative rather than just being the number reported on that day specifically.

[A snapshot of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnacA.png)

To try and produce daily figures for each country, I have been trying to subtract the previous day/cell's total from the following day; however when I did it using transform and ifelse it was only going by date so the daily figures being produced were global rather than specific to that country

However anytime I tried to use group_by(country_id) or mutate() I get the following error:

```
    Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 242.
i Input `..1` is `x_worldwide$country_id`.
i Input `..1` must be size 242 or 1, not 47432.
i The error occured in group 1: country_id = "AFG".
```

What I've been attempting to get to work:

```
    x_worldwide_with_dailies <- x_worldwide %>%
   group_by(x_worldwide$id)%>%   
   transform(x_worldwide, new_cases = (x_worldwide$confirmed[x_worldwide$date]-x_worldwide$confirmed[x_worldwide$date-1]))
```

The other option I'd been trying was with a rather convoluted IFELSE which does succesfully add a column but with incorrect values

```
x_worldwide_with_dailies_if_option <- x_worldwide %>%
    transform(daily_new_confirmed_per_country = ifelse(x_worldwide$confirmed[x_worldwide$date[x_worldwide$country_id]]
                 ==x_worldwide$confirmed[x_worldwide$date-1[x_worldwide$country_id]], 0,
                  x_worldwide$confirmed[x_worldwide$date[x_worldwide$country_id]]
                  -x_worldwide$confirmed[x_worldwide$date-1[x_worldwide$country_id]]))
```

Not sure where to go from here really, am I doing something fundamentally incorrect or not applying the right functions?

Many thanks

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: The lag() function in the dplyr package will help you. You seem to be combining base code with tidyverse syntax (and I think data.table code).  group_by() is part of tidyverse (dplyr package) and it uses non-standard evaluation, which means you write group_by(id) not group_by(x_worldwide$id).  I don't know which version of transform() you are using.  Please be sure to include the library(packageName) statements in your code examples. That will help us help you when you use functions that are not in base R.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't reference the original frame in a pipe *unless* you truly mean the value of the frame before any of the pipe happened.
2. While `transform` is similar to `mutate` in many ways, it is not aware of `dplyr` grouping, so it sees the whole frame at once (ergo incorrect values).
3. (You likely want/need `diff` or `left_join`, though it's unclear given the question.)

### Don't reference the original frame in the pipe

A first cut might look like this:

```r
x_worldwide_with_dailies <- x_worldwide %>%
   group_by(id) %>%   
   mutate(new_cases = (confirmed[date]-confirmed[date-1]))
```

(I have my doubts that this will work, though, since `confirmed[date]` seems wrong. If `date` is a `Date`-class object, then it's like doing `x <- 1:10; x[Sys.Date()]` ... what does that mean?)

In general, don't reference `x_worldwide` in any of the second-or-subsequent functions in a pipeline. (The only thing you *may* need is a `.` to reflect the current (sub)frame value at that point in the pipe.)

Realize that in pipes, the data that a particular function sees is very likely different than the value of the frame at the beginning of the pipe. For instance,

```r
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4L) %>%
  mutate(disp2 = mtcars$disp + 20) # fails
```

When `mutate` is called, the data coming to it is only 11 rows, but `mtcars` still refers to the original frame at the beginning of the pipe and therefore has 32 rows. Assuming you understand why you can't assign 32 values into 11 rows, then the rationale should be come clear. The effect is similar with `group_by`: the `+` operator only sees a vector of length 11 the first time ... then 7 the next (cyl=6), then 14 (cyl=8) the third and final time.

More plainly:

> The ***current value of the frame*** (at any point in the pipe) is not necessarily the same as the ***original value of the frame***, as affected by `mutate`, `filter`, and `group_by` (to name a few).

### `mutate` instead of `transform`

See this code:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  transform(disp0 = mean(disp)) %>%
  as_tibble()
# # A tibble: 32 x 12
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb disp0
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4  231.
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4  231.
#  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1  231.
#  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1  231.
#  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  231.
#  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1  231.
#  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4  231.
#  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2  231.
#  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2  231.
# 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4  231.
# # ... with 22 more rows

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(disp0 = mean(disp)) %>%
  as_tibble()
# # A tibble: 32 x 12
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb disp0
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4  183.
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4  183.
#  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1  105.
#  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1  183.
#  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  353.
#  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1  183.
#  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4  353.
#  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2  105.
#  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2  105.
# 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4  183.
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

See that `disp0` is different? That's because when you use `transform`, the average is calculated on the whole frame at a time (`mean(mtcars$disp)` is 230.72), ignoring the grouping. (You *can* approximate it using `%>% do(transform(., disp0 = mean(disp)))`, though the order is changed.)

---

### Ultimately, `confirmed[date]`

In the end, I think you have two ways forward for this portion of code:

- if you are looking for the change in `confirmed` (per `id`), then consider `new_cases = c(NA, diff(confirmed))`. This *assumes* that all `date` values are both monotonic-increasing and no gaps.
- if there is the possibility of gaps (or out-of-order), then you should consider a `left_join` (or base R's `merge`) on a mid-pipe modified frame. I think this branch of my answer delves into a new topic entirely, so I'll leave it to you to ask a new question once you have the basics working (and can provide usable sample data).